# Checkout page is not working in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Onepage checkout is not working. When i do research I found out that it is not actually getting the JS. link: http://farmafrique.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/

Does anyone have any solution to this?

Comment: There is something wrong with your javascript. Try to un-minify it and the minify it again.

Comment: Seems like some of your JavaScripts are relatively declared, see those URLs:  http://farmafrique.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/menu/main.js / http://farmafrique.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/menu/modernizr.js. Thus, those files are not found and may cause problems as well.

Comment: I have removed those inline js.but the same problem occuring again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a Prototype / jQuery issue

Read this https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Then, unmerge your JS files to see the order they are loaded. The order is very important when using both JS libraries

Then, use the `noConflict()` code after the jQuery include

Comment: Thanks bro..its working....just on onepage.html page the js i have to make all those no conflict